# Set the reference from a report to its Data Source using SOAP?

Tags: soap, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am writing a script for RS.EXE tool to deploy reports onto a server running Microsoft SQL Reporting Services 2008 R2.  Using the Mgmt2010 SOAP endpoint,  I am able to upload the reports (rdl files) just fine,  but they need a bit of additional help in order to be able to find the shared Data Sources that are on the server.

How can I use the SOAP service to properly configure the data source references associated with a report after I have uploaded it?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a DataSourceReference object and set its Reference property to the path to the shared data source.

Create a DataSource object.  Set the Name property to the name of the shared dataset *as known by the report*.  This might be different than the file name of the shared data source.  Set the Item property to the DataSourceReference object created above.

Finally, call SetItemDataSources with the path to the report and the DataSource object.